# SQL Server: select has too many columns for insert

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm trying to run this query and I keep getting this error:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

This error comes after I try doing INSERT INTO #tempTable SELECT....  It worked just fine when I had only 2 columns for each temp table, but now that I've added a third, it keeps giving me this error even though it appears to be selecting 3 columns to insert into the table with 3 columns.

The query overall is trying to get a few column values, (customer ids, contacts, and a salesman id) over different tables, but the problems have come from needing to root out duplicate customer IDs and making sure that only 1 salesman and 1 contact showing up for each customer. If it wasn't for the salemen id, the query would work perfectly.  Here is what I have so far:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable
if object_id('tempdb..#tempTable2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable2

CREATE TABLE #tempTable(
CustomerID int,
ContactName nvarchar(50),
SalesmenID nvarchar(4)
)

CREATE TABLE #tempTable2(
CustomerID int,
ContactName nvarchar(50),
SalesmenID nvarchar(4)
)


INSERT INTO #tempTable 
    (CustomerID, ContactName,SalesmenID)
    SELECT Customers.[Customer ID],Salesmen.[4 Letter ID],
    CASE([Customer Contact].defaultprintonorder) 
        WHEN 0 
        THEN 'zzzzzzz_NOCONTACT'
        ELSE
        [Customer Contact].[Contact Name]
        END as ContactName
    From Customers
    LEFT JOIN [Customer Contact] on Customers.[Customer ID]=[Customer Contact].[Customer ID]
    Left Join [Customer Salesmen] On Customers.[Customer ID]=[Customer Salesmen].[Customer ID]
    INNER JOIN Salesmen on [Customer Salesmen].[Salesman Name]=Salesmen.[Salesman Name]
WHERE Customers.[Customer ID] NOT IN(SELECT CustomerID FROM #tempTable)
GROUP BY Customers.[Customer ID], [Contact Name], DefaultPrintOnOrder


INSERT INTO #tempTable2  (CustomerID, ContactName,SalesmenID)
SELECT distinct CustomerID, '', SalesmenID FROM #tempTable 

UPDATE  #TempTable2 SET 
    #tempTable2.CustomerID=#tempTable.CustomerID, 
    #tempTable2.ContactName=#tempTable.ContactName
FROM 
    #TempTable2
    INNER JOIN #TempTable ON #TempTable2.CustomerID=#TempTable.CustomerID

SELECT Salesmen.[4 Letter ID],
       [Customers].[Customer ID], 
       [Customer Contact].[Contact Name]
FROM Customers
Right JOIN #TempTable2 ON
    Customers.[Customer ID]=#TempTable2.CustomerID
Right JOIN [Customer Salesmen] ON
    #TempTable2.CustomerID=[Customer Salesmen].[Customer ID]
INNER JOIN  
    [Salesmen] ON
    [Customer Salesmen].[Salesman Name]=Salesmen.[Salesman Name]
LEFT JOIN 
    [Customer Contact] ON
    #TempTable2.[CustomerID]=[Customer Contact].[Customer ID]
```

**EDIT:**
I added SalesmenID to the inserts, but now I'm getting this error message 3 times:

> Invalid column name 'SalesmenID'.

It comes up once for the temptable insert and twice for the temptable2 insert

Comment: is CustomerID a unique int indexer? You might not have edit permissions on that.

Comment: You have listed 2 columns in the `INSERT` (CustomerID, ContactName) but have three in the `SELECT` statement.

Comment: edited the post after I fixed that mistake.  Now its giving me a different error

Comment: RIGHT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN. Wow my head hurts.

Comment: how do you think I feel?  I've been staring at this for the past 8 hours

Comment: Can you give us a little more of a hint? What line number does the new error occur on? What happens when you try simplifying the query a little bit? (Drop the #temp tables from the equation, what results do you see when you run the very first INSERT/SELECT without the INSERT part?)

Comment: The errors are showing up for 
    INSERT INTO #tempTable 
        (CustomerID, ContactName,SalesmenID)
and 
    INSERT INTO #tempTable2 
        (CustomerID, ContactName,SalesmenID)

When I take out the references to salemenID, the salesmen table, etc. the query works just fine.  When I try to get just one salesmen per customer though is when I get the problem.  I'm using the temp tables to get populate the list of customers properly.

I'm not sure what you mean by dropping the temp tables from the equation.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but that doesn't make sense. Unless you've spelled the column name wrong, there is no other place that is mentioned except in the `INSERT` list. And I don't understand why you would get the error three times. Are you sure the code in the question is *exactly* the code you're running when you get the error?

Comment: Yeah, its exactly the same as what I have.  I'm working in Enterprise Manager's Query Analyzer for SQL Server 2000 to clarify, I don't know if there's maybe some minor syntax mistake that's causing the problem

Comment: Make sure you drop the temp tables first then run the rest of the script. You may still have old versions of them hanging around that confuses the parser so the whole batch doesn't run.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to store 3 values (Customers.[Customer ID], Salesmen.[4 Letter ID], ContactName) in 2 fields (CustomerID, ContactName)

```
    INSERT INTO #tempTable 
    (CustomerID, ContactName)
    SELECT Customers.[Customer ID],Salesmen.[4 Letter ID],
    CASE([Customer Contact].defaultprintonorder) 
    WHEN 0 
    THEN 'zzzzzzz_NOCONTACT'
    ELSE
    [Customer Contact].[Contact Name]
    END as ContactName
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the problem is where you indicated?

This insert has 2 destination columns and 3 select columns:

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable 
    (CustomerID, ContactName)    -- 2 columns

    SELECT Customers.[Customer ID], --column 1
            Salesmen.[4 Letter ID], --column 2
    CASE([Customer Contact].defaultprintonorder) -- column 3!
        WHEN 0 
        THEN 'zzzzzzz_NOCONTACT'
        ELSE
        [Customer Contact].[Contact Name]
        END as ContactName
    From Customers...
```